# Jenkinsfile trigger whenever there is a new commit in the branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers

I have a multibranch job that scans branches and create a pipeline from Jenkinsfile in the branch.
I want a build in the branch to trigger automatically upon a commit being merged into that branch.

i looked at the trigger documenation. it says
"The triggers currently available are cron, pollSCM and upstream."

i think both cron and pollSCM will trigger even if there is no new commit and they are time based so it wouldnt be upon when a commit is merged

Comment: This is not a Jenkins issue, it depends on the SCM that you used (e.g. github, gitlab, bitbucket...). Basically, you have to add hooks on the repository to call jenkins to perform your build.
With `pollSCM`, Jenkins will check your SCM each time you define to see if there is some modifications.
Please let me know what do you use, maybe I can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git/Bibtbucket for your repository you could use the build trigger, based on webhook connection between your Git/Bitbucket repo and Jenkins instance (In the settings of the repo -> Webhooks and there -> new hook with this URL -> http://Jeknins-url/bitbucket-hook/ ) and this will allow the Jenkins to build whenever a push to that project is made. It will run only the job for the branch which got the push command and the merging to a branch is considered as a push, so i assume this will resolve your problem.

[image: This is the option if you are using the "Bitbucker Server" plugin in your Jenkins]